# Send SQL Server command to move data (on server) from Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ado, dao

I would like to have an Access VBA sub that sends an instruction to a SQL Server database to copy some data from one of the remote tables to another table (at least one of the tables is not linked to the local Access database).  I want this to all happen on the server, as this is a lot of data.

I'm trying something like the following, but it returns an run-time error 3065 (Cannot execute a select query).  Any insight into how to fix?  Is there some reason I couldn't do this from Access?

Also, I'm using a DAO approach, but is there a better approach (ADO?)?  Somewhat new to this so not always sure I understand the nuances of the different approaches.

```
Public Sub myTest()

Setup:
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    Set dbs = CurrentDb()
    Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

qdf.SQL = "INSERT INTO tmp SELECT [Applicant], [CaseName], [DecisionDate], [Filed], [Docket] " _
       & "FROM Cases WHERE [DecisionDate] >= '01/01/2018';"

qdf.Connect = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};server=myServer;database=myDB;"

qdf.Execute

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you include `qdf.ReturnsRecords = False` after `qdf.Connect`?

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if it makes a difference whether I use the passthrough option in the execute line?  Like  "qdf.Execute dbSQLPassThrough"?  If all of the stuff is on the server, wouldn't it have to be processed on the server no matter what?  My query seems to work either way, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Actually it returns type = 0 (which I looked up, and is dbQSelect).  Strangely, that is the type even if I use the dbSQLPassThrough option.  Well, it's got to be running on the server.  I don't understand it, but seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks ok. I would “test” the sql first by running the exact same command by using SQL management studio.

As for your code? It also looks ok, but I find it MUCH better to save a PT query and thus you don’t have to mess with the connection string in code. And thus your code becomes:

```
With CurrentDB.querydefs("MyPassR")
  .SQL = "INSERT INTO tmp SELECT [Applicant], [CaseName], [DecisionDate], [Filed], [Docket] " & _
  "FROM Cases WHERE [DecisionDate] >= '01/01/2018';"
  .ReturnsRecords = False
  .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll consider that approach.  My concern is that the SQL statement will have to change on the fly a lot.  If I update a CurrentDB.,querydef repeatedly, is that the kind of thing that could bloat my DB?

Comment: Oh, and I tested in SSMS before I transitioned it to VBA, so the query syntax is good.

Comment: Ok, perhaps the connection string is wrong? As noted, create a PT query, test some select, or some command from Access (make well note that you have to manual set returnsrecords = true or false depending on the kind of command). So do a simple select in that PT query - see if it works. If it does, then try my PT example code as per above - it is nice easy code, and you don't mess with connection strings etc in code for this approach. So create the PT query - try a few things to ensure it works, and then simply try the code as per my example.

Comment: Changing the SQL repeatedly is not a problem in regards to bloat. So you can change the above as often as  you need. This is likely better then creating a temp querydef in terms of bloat anyway, and as noted, you don't mess with connection strings in code. Your re-link code thus can (and should) include re-linking of PT queries.